# Binding service data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that is used to share data between 2 controllers and retrieves a data list:

```
myApp.service('DataService', function($http) {
    this.data = [];
    this.loadData = function() {
        $http.get('/api/data').success(function(data) {
            this.data= data;
        })
    };

});
```

which is called in my controller:

```
myApp.controller('appController', function($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.DataService= DataService;
    DataService.loadData();
});
```

and displayed here:

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
    <li ng-repeat='item in DataService.data'>
        <a href="#item/{{item.ID}}"> View Item</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

When this is ran, it doesn't display anything.
I have ran it with some alert boxes and can see that the data list is populated with the data I want to display but no information is displayed otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You're using your service incorrectly. Right now, it's going to be hard for Angular to watch the property on your service for changes. Instead of storing the data as a property on itself, it should simply return it to the caller. Try:

```
myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.loadData = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/data').then(function(data) { return data; });
    }
}
```

Which is then called in the controller like:

```
myApp.controller('appController', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = dataService.loadData();
});
```

And bound to in the view like:

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data track by $id">
        <a href="#item/{{ item.ID }}">View Item</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using a service as I want to share data between 2 controllers

Comment: @user3644980 - Using the service for that sharing is the wrong way to do it though. Are the two controllers nested or separate?

Comment: The 2 controllers are nested, what would you suggest is the best way of doing this?

Comment: @user3644980 - If you're nesting the controllers, the inner controller's scope should inherit from the outer controller's scope. Once you add `$scope.data` in the outer, it should be there for the inner as well (may need to use `$scope.$parent.data`, I'm not sure off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

Have to return a promise and use `.then` to access it:

```
this.loadData = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/data').then(function(data) {
        return data.result
    })
};
```

Ctrl:

```
DataService.loadData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.DataService = data;
});
```

Comment: Assuming the value is going to be bound, there's no need for `then`. You can simply return the promise and allow the binding to handle the promise.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It looks like they removed the promise unwrapping during binding. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've got this right but...by calling the method on the service itself instead of on the service assigned to the $scope won't that make it Angular JS miss the watch on the data property completely?